# Efficient Way to Build Large Scale Hierarchical Data Tree Path

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a large dataset (think: big data) of network elements that form a tree-like network.

A toy dataset looks like this:

```
|   id | type   | parent_id   |
|-----:|:-------|:------------|
|    1 | D      | <NA>        |
|    2 | C      | 1           |
|    3 | C      | 2           |
|    4 | C      | 3           |
|    5 | B      | 3           |
|    6 | B      | 4           |
|    7 | A      | 4           |
|    8 | A      | 5           |
|    9 | A      | 3           |
```

*Important rules:*

- The root nodes (in the toy example of type D) and the leaf nodes (in the toy example of type A) cannot be connected with each other and amongst each other. I.e., a D node cannot be connected with another D node (vice-versa for A nodes) and an A node cannot directly be connected with a D node.
- For simplicity reasons, any other node type can randomly be connected in terms of types.
- The tree depth can be arbitrarily deep.
- The leaf node is always of type A.
- A leaf node does not need to be connected through all intermediate nodes. In reality there are only a handful intermediary nodes that are mandatory to pass through. This circumstance can be neglected for this example here.
- If you are to recommend doing it in Spark, the solution must be written with pyspark in mind.

What I would like to achieve is to build an efficient way (preferably in Spark) to calculate the tree-path for each node, like so:

```
|   id | type   | parent_id   | path                |
|-----:|:-------|:------------|:--------------------|
|    1 | D      | <NA>        | D:1                 |
|    2 | C      | 1           | D:1>C:2             |
|    3 | C      | 2           | D:1>C:2>C:3         |
|    4 | C      | 3           | D:1>C:2>C:3>C:4     |
|    5 | B      | 3           | D:1>C:2>C:3>B:5     |
|    6 | B      | 4           | D:1>C:2>C:3>C:4>B:6 |
|    7 | A      | 4           | D:1>C:2>C:3>C:4>A:7 |
|    8 | A      | 5           | D:1>C:2>C:3>B:5>A:8 |
|    9 | A      | 3           | D:1>C:2>C:3>A:9     |
```

*Note*:

Each element in the tree path is constructed like this: `id:type`.

If you have other efficient ways to store the tree path (e.g., closure tables) and calculate them, I am happy to hear them as well. However, the runtime for calculation must be really low (less than an hour, preferably minutes) and retrieval later needs to be in the area of few seconds.

The ultimate end goal is to have a data structure that allows me to aggregate any network node underneath a certain node efficiently (runtime of a few seconds at most).

The actual dataset consisting of around 3M nodes can be constructed like this:

*Note*:

- The commented node_counts that produces the above shown toy examples
- The distribution of the node elements is close to reality.

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
random.seed(1337)
node_counts = {'A': 1424383, 'B': 596994, 'C': 234745, 'D': 230937, 'E': 210663, 'F': 122859, 'G': 119453, 'H': 57462, 'I': 23260, 'J': 15008, 'K': 10666, 'L': 6943, 'M': 6724, 'N': 2371, 'O': 2005, 'P': 385}
#node_counts = {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 1}
elements = list()
candidates = list()
root_type = list(node_counts.keys())[-1]
leaf_type = list(node_counts.keys())[0]
root_counts = node_counts[root_type]
leaves_count = node_counts[leaf_type]
ids = [i + 1 for i in range(sum(node_counts.values()))]
idcounter = 0
for i, (name, count) in enumerate(sorted(node_counts.items(), reverse=True)):
    for _ in range(count):
        _id = ids[idcounter]
        idcounter += 1
        _type = name
        if i == 0:
            _parent = None
        else:
            # select a random one that is not a root or a leaf
            if len(candidates) == 0: # first bootstrap case
                candidate = random.choice(elements)
            else:
                candidate = random.choice(candidates)
            _parent = candidate['id']
        _obj = {'id': _id, 'type': _type, 'parent_id': _parent}
        #print(_obj)
        elements.append(_obj)
        if _type != root_type and _type != leaf_type:
            candidates.append(_obj)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(elements).astype({'parent_id': 'Int64'})
```

In order to produce the tree path in pure python with the above toy data you can use the following function:

```py
def get_hierarchy_path(df, cache_dict, ID='id', LABEL = 'type', PARENT_ID = 'parent_id', node_sep='|', elem_sep=':'):
    def get_path(record):
        if pd.isna(record[PARENT_ID]):
            return f'{record[LABEL]}{elem_sep}{record[ID]}'
        else:
            if record[PARENT_ID] in cache_dict:
                parent_path = cache_dict[record[PARENT_ID]]
            else:
                try:
                    parent_path = get_path(df.query(f'{ID} == {record[PARENT_ID]}').iloc[0])
                except IndexError as e:
                    print(f'Index Miss for {record[PARENT_ID]} on record {record.to_dict()}')
                    parent_path = f'{record[LABEL]}{elem_sep}{record[ID]}'
                cache_dict[record[PARENT_ID]] = parent_path
            return f"{parent_path}{node_sep}{record[LABEL]}{elem_sep}{record[ID]}"
    return df.apply(get_path, axis=1)
df['path'] = get_hierarchy_path(df, dict(), node_sep='>')
```

What I have already tried:

- Calculating in pure python with the above function on the large dataset takes me around 5.5 hours. So this is not really a solution. Anything quicker than this is appreciated.
- Technically using the spark `graphframes` package, I could use BFS. This would give me a good solution for individual leave nodes, but it does not scale to the entire network.
- I think Pregel is the way to go here. But I do not know how to construct it in Pyspark.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution for this challenge relies now no longer on Spark but on SQL.
I load the whole dataset to a Postgres DB and place a Unique Index on id, type and parent_id.

Then using the following query, I can calculate the path:

```
with recursive recursive_hierarchy AS (
    -- starting point
    select 
        parent_id
        , id 
        , type 
        , type || ':' || id as path
        , 1 as lvl
    from hierarchy.nodes

    union all
    -- recursion
    select
        ne.parent_id as parent_id
        , h.id 
        , h.type 
        , ne.type || ':' || ne.id || '|' || h.path as path
        , h.lvl + 1 as lvl
    from (
        select * 
        from hierarchy.nodes
    ) ne
    inner join recursive_hierarchy h
        on ne.id = h.parent_id
), paths as (
    -- complete results
    select 
        *
    from recursive_hierarchy
), max_lvl as (
    -- retrieve the longest path of a network element
    select
        id
        , max(lvl) as max_lvl
    from paths
    group by id
)
-- all results with only the longest path of a network element
select distinct
    , p.id
    , p.type
    , p.path
from paths p
    inner join max_lvl l
        on p.id = l.id
        and p.lvl = l.max_lvl
```